How can I hang a 10 lb pendulum light from a ribbed concrete ceiling without drilling holes?
I live in a loft with a high concrete ceiling, exposed cement beams about 6 inches wide. I want to hang a pendulum light that is about 10 lbs. I cannot drill so I was thinking of using a C clamp or bar clamp across a beam. Is this possible/a good idea? Do you have any suggestions for the installation and/or safety?


From the photo, it looks like the beams have sloped sides. If so, you aren't going to be able to clamp to them well.

why can't you drill? or what can you do?  they make nail-in picture hooks that could work...

For clamps or pressure holding devices, you would want a type with points/steel cones that might dig into the cement, not flat surfaces that might slip.

@keshlam, the beams appear square to my eye.

If  so, ignore me.

Beam shape is hard to determine from pic—there does appear to be a fillet at the ends of the beams that tapers top to bottom that may be throwing off the perspective.

OP, how important are aesthetics here?

A C-clamp or dedicated utility clamp is a good idea. The concrete can handle that compression if you aren't applying force near the corners. If it's up at least a couple inches it'll be fine, within reason. You could pad it with wooden blocks or plywood scrap to prevent surface marring. It'll still hold well if snug enough.
A bar clamp is probably not a good idea. Its jaws are likely to be too short to get the kind of offset I mentioned above, or to reliably hold position, and you definitely don't want to span between two ribs and apply lateral force. While those cast beams are certainly high-grade concrete, there is at least some potential for cracking.

Wooden pads would improve the grip on concrete compared to metal because the wood will deform to fit the surface; they'll also spread the clamping force.  A lot of the one-handed bar clamps have quite a decent throat depth and would work nicely, with their rubber-covered plastic jaws

I mostly agree, though the one-handed clamps I own don't supply adequate clamping force (at least with my wimpy grip). Also, the plastic jaws tend to slip out of the rubber pads. I wouldn't trust them here.

I'm quite tempted to try using mine as a chin-up bar, if I had somewhere suitable, and it wasn't expensive.  But they are in general prone to poor design leading to the rubber working loose when not in use, then being insecure in use

You could look for an extending bar with pads on either end that turns or ratchets to change and lock the length, then wedge it between two of the beams. Something like bars used to secure cargo (like this - or these). There are some ceiling fan mounting brackets that adjust the same way and might work.

A tension rod for drapery or shower curtain could work, if you can find one that will support the weight and stay in place against the bare concrete. There are other kinds of extending bar devices, too. You will want something that is intended to tighten and/or lock in position more or less permanently. Most bar clamps for woodworking are only meant to be temporary.
